# sql command with join always fails

Tags: c#, sql, join, oledb

I am making a C# project with OleDB connected to an Access database and i have this code:

```
string sql = "select * from cashflow  join dates on txt_cashflow_id=txt_dates_id";
```

but although the code looks ok, it gives me an exception - doesn't matter what i do (VS is giving me the exception not in English so i cant quote it but it's something like "Syntax error in FROM clause")

I have tried to switch tables, switch columns and select only one column (and not all with *) but it didn't solve it.

What is the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the table names in front of your fields and inner join...

```
string sql = "select * from cashflow inner join dates on
     cashflow.txt_cashflow_id=dates.txt_dates_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Microsoft Access documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx) the word `JOIN` doesn't **imply** `INNER JOIN`, so just change your statement to this:

```
select * from cashflow inner join dates on txt_cashflow_id=txt_dates_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query `select * from cashflow  join dates on txt_cashflow_id=txt_dates_id`

like below

Either:

```
select * from cashflow  inner join dates on txt_cashflow_id=txt_dates_id
```

OR

```
select * from cashflow,dates on cashflow.txt_cashflow_id=dates.txt_dates_id
```